# min max and range of the matrix: How to mathematically write that?

Tags: matrices, notation, maxima-minima

I have two questions about mathematical notation.

1. Let F be the matrix of $i$ rows and $j$ columns. I want to found min and max values of that matrix for every row. Currently, I have this

$$l_i = \min\limits_{j \in \{1, ..., n\}} f_{ij}, \quad i = 1, ..., m, $$
$$u_i = \max\limits_{j \in \{1, ..., n\}} f_{ij}, \quad i = 1, ..., m, $$

Ideally, I would like to write this such that it would result in another matrix with two columns, one of lower bounds and the other one with the upper bounds. How would I write that? Any other suggestions to write this are greatly appreciated. Could you write it like this?
\begin{equation}
\textbf{D} = [\min\limits_{j \in \{1, ..., n\}} f_{ij}, \max\limits_{j \in \{1, ..., n\}} f_{ij}], \quad i = 1, ..., m.  
\end{equation}

2. How do you write mathematically the range between two column vectors with $m$ observations? I have this:
   $$\textbf{Rng} = |\min(\textbf{F}) - \max(\textbf{F}) |$$
   Is this okay?

Comment: I haven't read your suggestion for $D$. Even if it's correct I wouldn't use it. Write words instead. Define your lists of lower and upper bounds and then tell your reader to put them in a two column matrix.

Comment: Agree with the previous comment. If getting the vector $Rng$ is your ultimate aim, then just write something like "Let $Rng_i$ be the range of values in each row $F_i$ of $F$".

Comment: Oki that sounds good. thank you! :)